# Virtual disc, missing bootloader. How to boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, vmware, grub2

I had a netbook with HDD partitioned into 3. On one of the partitions (say /dev/sda2) i had an instance of Crunchbang Linux installed. I had backed it up using 'dd' command (dd if=/dev/sda2 of=<...>) into an external HDD.

Now, I have changed the partioning scheme on that netbook, so image no longer fits into new partitons which are smaller, but I wanted to look at some config files on my old instance, so I decided to convert the raw backup into vmware (.vmdk) file and create a VM and fire up the instance.

But..looks like at that time, I must be having the /boot on a separate partition (/dev/sda1) which I forgot to backup :(. Now VMware instance does not boot because it cannot find the Operating system on the virtual hard disc.

Is there any remedy? can I create a small virtual disc and install grub2 and kernel images into it inside the VM and boot from there? How? any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to boot off of this disk image? You just want to see some files on it, right? Couldn't you just mount it as a secondary filesystem on a working VM (or on the physical host, for that matter)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Crashbang Linux VM, boot your VM from is and then mount either the VMDK or the original backup as a secondary volume.  See from page 7 of the VMWare userguide on how to mount an image as a separate partition this [here](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwareDiskMount.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to look up some files, you can easily mount the .vmdk file in your own Linux, without any need of a VM:

```
 losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/your/file.vmdk
 losetup -o 32256 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop0
 mount /dev/loop1 /your/mount/point
```

The trick lies in the offset, 32256 in this case. This will work for the first partition, but if you do not wish to mount the first partition, after the first command you will have to use *fdisk* on the loop device:

```
 fdisk -l /dev/loop0
```

Then the offset is the product of bytes per sector times the start of the partition you wish to mount.

If you also want to boot it I *think* that all you need to do is to copy the /boot directory from any other running installation of Crunchbang of the same architecture into into your old image, chroot into it, update grub, and off you go. You can do that 
from an instance of a Crunchbang VM, while it is not running: just save the image of the
new instance into a new vmdk file, mount that just like the other one, copy /boot from the new to the old image, chroot into the old image, update grub, et voilà.